# Regular Expression for whole world

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, vb6

**First of all, I use C# 4.0 to parse the code of a VB6 application.**
I have some old VB6 code and about 500+ copies of it. And I use a regular expression to grab all kinds of global variables from the code. The code is described as "Yuck" and some poor victim still has to support this. So I'm hoping to help this poor sucker a bit by generating overviews of specific constants. (And yes, it should be rewritten but it ain't broke, so...) 
This is a sample of a code line I need to match, in this case all boolean constants:

```
Public Const gDemo = False           'Is this a demo version
```

And this is the regular expression I use at this moment:

```
Public\s+Const\s+g(?'Name'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s+=\s+(?'Value'[0-9]*)
```

And I think it too is yuckie, since the * at the end of the boolean group. But if I don't use it, it will only return 'T' or 'F'. I want the whole word.

Is this the proper RegEx to use as solution or is there an even nicer-looking option?

FYI, I use similar regexs to find all string constants and all numeric constants. Those work just fine. And basically the same .BAS file is used for all 50 copies but with different values for all these variables. By parsing all files, we have a good overview of how every version is configured.
And again, yes, we need to rebuild the whole project from scratch since it becomes harder to maintain these days. But it works and we need the manpower for other tasks. It just needs the occasional tweaks...

Comment: `Public\s+Const\s+g(?<Name>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s+=\s+(?<Value>[0-9]*)`

Comment: Do u want like this https://regex101.com/r/oN1xJ7/1

Comment: You can use [ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) grammar to parse VB6 like [Rubber Duck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) does. There is a ready-made parser in the repo.

Comment: I don't need to parse the whole code. I just need to grab the global variables of every copy of this project. These variables serve as configuration settings and vary per customer. All copies do share one generic library so changes to code will be done to all, but certain customer-specific settings are per copy. I need those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use:** `Public\s+Const\s+g(?<Name>[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s+=\s+(?<Value>False|True)`

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN1xJ7/1)**

Comment: Ah, I made things too complex. :)

Comment: @Wim ten Brink  thanks and i am glad to see accepting my answer.